# p4 submit files not in client view

Tags: perforce, perforce-client-spec

Is there a way to submit a file that is not part of the client view?

My client looks like:

```
//dir1/...
-//dir1/dir2/...
```

I am trying to create a **new file** that is a few megabytes at `//dir1/dir2/file1` and submit it without syncing `//dir1/dir2/` (which can be multi-gigabyte).

Is there any way to force-submit a file that doesn't exist in the client view if I can guarantee the base directory (`//dir1/dir2`) exists in the Perforce depot?

Edit: Yes, I understand that I can add this file to the client view, but my question, specifically, as above, is: **"Is there any way to force-submit a file that doesn't exist in the client view"?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(**Edit**: Clarifying my answer, to try to more directly answer the (clarified) question)

No, there is no way to submit a file that doesn't exist in the client view. Without the information in the client view, the server doesn't know how to ask the client for the content of the file to be submitted, as the client view is what specifies **which physical file on the client machine** contains the content to be submitted.

As a workaround, you can refine your client view still further:

```
//dir1/...          //my-ws/location/dir1/...
-//dir1/dir2/...    //my-ws/location/dir1/dir2-files-I-don't-care-about/...
//dir1/dir2/file1   //my-ws/location/dir1/dir2/file1
```

You can read this as: "include everything in `dir1`, excluding everything in `dir1/dir2`, except for `dir1/dir2/file1`, which is specifically to be included."

After adjusting your view, you can use `p4 add //dir1/dir2/file1` as you expect.

The order of the mapping lines is critical here, as described by this sentence from `p4 help views`:

```
If more than one mapping line refers to the same files, the later
mapping line overrides the earlier one.
```

If you wish, once you have submitted the file, you can remove that line from your view spec (and re-sync your client), to simplify your client back to its prior definition.

Comment: Wonderful answer. When I do `p4 client -o` I get the view as `//depot/dir1`  `/root/dir2` i.e the depot path and the mapped client path are adjacent to each other. How to make such a mapping in this type of client configuration?

Comment: It's not clear to me from the question where you want the depot directory to be in the workspace -- if you can express it in that form (e.g. "I would like //depot/dir1 to be synced to my workspace as /root/blah/dir1 and //depot/dir2 to be synced as /root/blah/dir2") someone who's familiar with client views can very readily show you how to set up the view.

Comment: While informative, this does not address the OP's question: "Is there any way to force-submit a file that doesn't exist in the client view"?

Comment: @ElleFie No, there is no way to submit a file that doesn't exist in the client view. Without the information in the client view, the server doesn't know how to ask the client for the content of the file to be submitted, as the client view is what specifies **which physical file** on the client machine contains the content to be submitted.

Comment: Okay, can you submit that as an answer rather than a comment?